# Discretize anonymous function matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function called `fun`, and I need to run the following code:

```
polarfun = @(r,theta) fun(r.*cos(theta),r.*sin(theta)).*r;
p = @(theta) integral(@(r)polarfun(r,theta),0,Inf);
```

After this I need to build a vector consisting of samples of the function `p`

I'm doing it like this (`n` is previously defined):

```
v = 0:2*pi/n:2*pi;
for i=1:n+1
    samplesofp(i) = p(v(i)); 
end
```

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this, since I need it to run as fast as possible.

Comment: I may be missing something, but `p` is getting only `theta` as input, where does the `r` come from?

Comment: It's basically a change of variable, from `x,y` (cartesian) in `fun` to `r,theta` in `polarfun` (polar coordinates), then I integrate over `r` from `0` to `Inf` so `r` goes away-

Comment: Try `samplesofp = arrayfun(p, v);`. Also how is `fun` defined? It can be relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You van either use `arrayfun`, as suggested in comments:

```
samplesofp = arrayfun(p,v);
```

or set `integral` for an array input:

```
p = @(theta) integral(@(r)polarfun(r,theta),0,Inf,'ArrayValued',true);
samplesofp = p(v);
```

the second option is probably faster:

```
fun  = @(x,y) x+y;
polarfun = @(r,theta) fun(r.*cos(theta),r.*sin(theta)).*r;
p = @(theta) integral(@(r)polarfun(r,theta),0,Inf);
pa = @(theta) integral(@(r)polarfun(r,theta),0,Inf,'ArrayValued',true);
n = 5;
v = (0:2*pi/n:2*pi).';

t = timeit(@() arrayfun(p,v));
ta = timeit(@() pa(v));
```

the time of the first option `t` = 0.057581 sec. while the time of the second option `ta` = 0.010085 sec. But it may be depended on `fun`, which I just invented here as a very simple function.

Comment: Thank you, I used the second option `ta`. Basically `fun` is a gaussian or a combination of gaussian distributions.